# Promise Angularjs 1.6 How can I force function to wait for api response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

Im using this plugin: http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/

I want to hook the `onPreview`

So on `onPreview` i try to make my api call:

```
   app.directive("markdowntextarea",function ($http, $q) { // inject $q
    return {
        link: function (el_scope, element, attr) {
            element.markdown(
                {
                    autofocus: false,
                    savable: false,
                    onPreview: function (e) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        if (e.isDirty()) {
                            var originalContent = e.getContent();
                            $http({
                                url: '/api/markdown/',
                                data: {"body": originalContent, "actual_format": "md"},
                                method: 'POST'
                            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                                console.log("successCallback", response.data.content);
                                deferred.resolve(response.data.content);
                            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                                console.log("errorCallback");
                                deferred.reject("error");
                            });
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve("");
                        }
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Console:

```
successCallback from api!!!
```

I got success response from api, the response.data.content is what I want to use. The problem here is the `return deferred.promise;` always return the original value. What can I do here? I'm really new in angularjs

Comment: what is your questrion? what do you want?

Comment: I would like to return the response from my call to api. At the moment I can't return it, always returning the original value. Thanks

Comment: You just have to call it onPreview().then(()=>{}). Is that what you mean? Otherwise your question is incomplete I guess. Post the complete code!

Comment: I will edit question. Give me a second

Comment: @dag I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With promises you can't return values at once, usually you return promise object called promise handle and using 'then' clause you wait for promise to resolve(successfully) or reject(failure).

In your case if you want to wait for response and then do something I suggest you call onPreview and use its then clause like:

```
onPreview(e).then(function(response){}, function(error){});
```

onPreview is already returning promise which should be thenable.

**After Edit:**

So onPreview is API method and is expecting a text not promise, now what you can do is define a function like `makePreview` or something:

```
function makePreview(e) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (e.isDirty()) {
        var originalContent = e.getContent();
        $http({
            url: '/api/markdown/',
            data: {"body": originalContent, "actual_format": "md"},
            method: 'POST'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("successCallback", response.data.content);
            deferred.resolve(response.config.data.body);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("errorCallback");
            deferred.reject("error");
        });
    } else {
        deferred.resolve("");
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and then your onPreview should look like this:

```
autofocus: false,
savable: false,
onPreview: function (e) {
    makePreview(e).then(function(response){
        e.setContent(response);
        return response;
    }, function(error){
        return error;
    });
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Could you tke  a look? thanks

Comment: hi, thanks. a noob question. the new function should be also inside the app.directive("markdowntextarea",function ($http, $q) {

Comment: if yes, I still got the original str, not the content from api call

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, is first time time I use Angular, also I have to finish this task today .

Comment: Yes and are you sure `response.data.content` contains correct values? you might want to debug the resolve statements from your browser developer tools

Comment: Yes. I got this on console :successCallback--------------> from API!!!  (is from the success call . Is that str I need

Comment: try changing this `deferred.resolve(response.data.content);` to `deferred.resolve('testing content');` and see if you get testing content as your new content also try console.log(response); to see which property in response contains the new content you look for and then pass that into deferred.resolve

Comment: I still got the originalContent

Comment: console.log(response); -> Object config : Object data : Object content : "from api!!!"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136259/discussion-between---and-62009030).

Comment: I have a last question. can you go to chat?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write angular in absolute sync way. Use the response in callback. 
If you need to control api requests' order, or wait for multiple requests, see doc of [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)